# Karma proxy not proxy external url

Tags: karma-jasmine

I am using karma-jasmine for unit testing but I have to connect to a running website for some startup/initialization stuff. 
My application is running at http://localhost:8086/app and I have set up the following proxies in karma.config,

```
proxies: {
    '/app': 'http://localhost:8086/app/'
}
```

However, when I run the test case, I see a Karma debug message as if it is trying to connect to my external app,

> DEBUG [proxy]: proxying request - /app/ to localhost:8086

but instead fails with the following error message,

> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR: DOMException{stack: 'Error: Failed to
>   execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:9876/app/'.

Note that the internal xmlhttprequest has used Karma's port (9876) instead of my app's port which is 8086.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Or am I not doing this right?